# Trouble reading in ANSI file to java program as byte[]

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader, ansi

I am attempting to read the data files located here: http://cis.jhu.edu/~sachin/digit/digit.html
into 28x28 images for image recognition in Java.  However I am having some trouble loading the data.  There are 1000 28x28 images stored in each file as a list of characters.  When I open the file in notepad++ it correctly displays that there are 784,000 characters in each file.  However, when I read them in java with a BufferedReader or Scanner using the same ANSI encoding they have less characters.  The exact number depends on which file it is but around 782,500.  I manually compared them and found that my java output is missing several control characters so I assume they are whats not being read.  I don't actually need the characters, just the unsigned byte values of the characters.  Does anyone know how I can get fix this?

Example code:

```
int count = 0;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream(inputFile), "windows-1252"));
while((line=in.readLine())!=null)
{
    count+=line.length();
}
```

My actual code is more complicated than this but this should count the number of chars and show a lower amount than the actual number because characters like File Separator and Data Link Escape are ignored.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try using a ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: ANSI? Do you mean ASCII? or Unicode?

Comment: @EJP No, OP means this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 Note the comments about the confusion with ANSI and ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` strip the line endings for you (carriage return and/or line feed) and just return the contents of the lines. Are those the only control characters that are missing?

You can use the `InputStream::read` method to read all data from the file, if you need the line endings. There are other ways to do it, too, with memory mapped files and ByteBuffers, for instance, but you probably don't need anything like that.

Comment: Thank you so much you saintly man, you just unstuck me after like 7 hours of trying.